# python: Will not return True or False inside my function

Tags: python

```
    def func(numbers, n):
        if n in numbers:
            return True
        else:
            return False

func([1,2,3], 2)
```

I get nothing as output in the console. Why is that?

Comment: cannot recreate, I'm getting `True` as output.

Comment: Hm, how are you running your code? I executed your code just fine in the console (or powershell more specifically)

Comment: if you execute this code as a file, you need to print the result

Comment: Im running it in pyCharm!

Comment: If you want to print something in the console, use `print`.

Comment: So I ran it in Shell and it works just fine, but when I do it in PyCharm I get nothing. Why is that?

Comment: change the last line to `print(func([1,2,3],2))`. to `print` the result of your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your function works fine and return True/False but you need add print to see what return in console.**

```
def func(numbers, n):
    if n in numbers:
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(func([1, 2, 3], 2))
```

You can also use print in your function to print in console True or False.

If you run code in Python Console return bool without print but if you want to run code from file you need add print then.